# Suggestions for Deploying Document-QA system using LLaMa-2 model

Tags: deployment, continuous-deployment, streamlit, large-language-model

I have built a document question answering system using LLaMa-2 large languae model, now I have to deploy the system across the organization.

Here are my questions :

- Will the system with (Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6238R CPU @ 2.20GHz, 2195 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 2 LogicalProcessor with 24GB RAM and GPU - Nvidia A40-12Q with 12gb) be able to handle the workload of  1000 users logging in?
- I have used Streamlit for my document QA, is it better to use streamlit or Chainlit?
- Which OS is better for production level deployment? Windows or Linux?

This is pretty new to me, So I would welcome all inputs and suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to the SO community! I think you will receive better help if you split your questions into 3 different questions and add more details to each. See [MRE link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for more details

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.